# VBA won't copy the next table, but keeps pasting the first instead

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

Set x = ThisWorkbook

Set y = Workbooks.Open("N:\\REAL PATH")

'Opens Data and Pastes Values

   x.Worksheets("Event Data").Range("Table1[#All]").Copy
   y.Worksheets("CoreData").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

   x.Worksheets("Comments").Range("Table2[#All]").Copy
   y.Worksheets("CommentsData").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


   x.Worksheets("Match Data").Range("Table3[#All]").Copy
   y.Worksheets("MatchDetails").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

   y.Close SaveChanges:=True



ActiveWorkbook.Save

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

After running the code, I go to the workbook named y, and I find that Table 1's data has been pasted three times. So, basically, the y.Worksheets lines are working properly but it won't copy data from Table 2 or 3. If I hit ctrl + g and type in "Table2[#All]" I am taken to the full Table 2, so I know that the range exists and that VBA should be able to find it. Table 1 contains quite a bit of data (131k rows + columns to DZ), but I don't know if that's relevant.

Comment: Interesting. You might be able to just use value transfer and avoid the clipboard.

Comment: Value transfer essentially works like pasting as values? I've heard it's faster with smaller datasets, but I don't actually know how to write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that creating and using intermediate variables greatly helps to clear up any problems in transferring data. Plus, you can look at these variables when debugging to verify they are correctly set.

Try something along these lines:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Example()
    Dim srcWB As Workbook
    Dim dstWB As Workbook
    Set srcWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set dstWB = Workbooks.Open("N:\\REAL PATH")

    Dim srcData As Range
    Dim dstData As Range
    Set srcData = srcWB.Sheets("Event Data").Range("Table1[#All]")
    Set dstData = dstWB.Sheets("CoreData").Range("A1").Resize(srcData.Rows.Count, _
                                                              srcData.Columns.Count)
    dstData.Value = srcData.Value

    Set srcData = srcWB.Sheets("Comments").Range("Table2[#All]")
    Set dstData = dstWB.Sheets("CommentsData").Range("A1").Resize(srcData.Rows.Count, _
                                                                  srcData.Columns.Count)
    dstData.Value = srcData.Value

    Set srcData = srcWB.Sheets("Match Data").Range("Table3[#All]")
    Set dstData = dstWB.Sheets("MatchDetails").Range("A1").Resize(srcData.Rows.Count, _
                                                                  srcData.Columns.Count)
    dstData.Value = srcData.Value

    dstWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

You've also confused using `ThisWorkbook` and later using `ActiveWorkbook`. It's not clear which on you're saving.

This type of "value only" data copy is very fast, and you may not need to disable events or screen updates. You still may need to disable these if you also have event handlers catching worksheet changes.

Comment: Worked like an absolute charm! Looks like I can access the clipboard while this code is running which is a massive plus for m1.